# How can I sent a PDF form to recipients that are determined by a value selected from a drop-down?

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, email-attachments

I created a PDF form using Adobe Acrobat that is designed to capture information and then allow the user to send the completed form to the people who need the information using a "Send" button.

I am brand spanking new to making forms (newer to code) and the code below I got from research on the internet. The code is in the button properties under Actions and Run a Javascript. **It is included here for reference. It works very well if the email recipients do not change.**

```
var cToAddr = "Email1@work.com;Email2@work.com;Email3@work.com";
var cCCAddr = "CCMail@work.com";
var cSubLine = "[Student Name / Employee Number] Situation";
var cBody = "Enter other information as desired."
this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cCc: cCCAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});
```

Now I need the form to go to different recipients based on the value selected from a drop-down menu on the form. For example, if Team 1 is selected from the dropdown, then I need the form to go to Team1@email.com. If Team 2 is selected, then I need the form to go to Team2@email.com, etc.

I do not know how to modify this code to make this happen nor have I been able to find new code that would do this and need assistance.

SOLVED:

```
var cToAddr = this.getField("Team").valueAsString;
```

was the only modification required to the original code, with "Team" being the name of the dropdown. One additional step was to put the recipient email addresses in the Export Value field of each associated dropdown option in the Dropdown Properties menu.

Works perfectly.

Comment: We have no idea which language or framework you are using. Some sort of VBA? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Acrobat and Javascript. Is this the information that you need? I see that someone rated my post as having put in no effort. I assure you that is not the case. As new as I am, it's quite possible that I've run across the answer in my research but don't know enough to recognize the answer, even after hours of research. That is why I reached out here.

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. Then please [edit] to provide sufficient detail to help us help you (in particular, add the [tag:javascript] tag so people who are familiar with that language can take a look, and people who aren't won't waste time on questions they have no way to answer). I don't know how you were able to conclude that someone thinks you put in "no effort" but we do ask that you familiarize yourself briefly with the help pages before asking a question.

Comment: I reviewed those but don't know what you need. The Minimal Reproducible Example information seems focused on debugging, which I am not. The code provided works well but does not do exactly what I need it to do. It was included for perspective so those providing assistance would know where I'm starting from. Was hoping that minimal modification of that code would achieve the objective. The javascript tag, also, does not seem to apply here. The "no effort" conclusion came from the "-1" at the top of the page.

Comment: The code you posted is insufficient because we don't know what `this` refers to. We should be able to copy/paste the code in your question and reproduce the situation you are asking about.

Comment: Maybe I am too new to get the assistance I need but here's it is simplified: I need a JS code that will attach a form to an email, the recipients of which are determined by a value selected from a drop-down. Can someone point me in the right direction? It seems a simple thing but I cannot find an answer, at least one that I understand.

Comment: The tooltip for the downvote says "The question does not demonstrate any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" but it could be clarified that any one of these is sufficient. The detailed guidance for downvoting in the help center is, again, more detailed and clear.

Comment: The "this" is part of the current code that works fine if I don't want the emails to change based on the aforementioned dropdown.

Comment: I added the [tag:pdf] and [tag:javascript] tags to your question. I'm not qualified enough in these topics to say for sure, but I am afraid it will need more details before someone can understand what it is that you are trying to ask. In the meantime, I find it troubling that you refused to add even the simple tag I asked you to add.

Comment: The code included I got from searching the internet. I have minimal understanding of it since, as stated, I am brand new to JS and Adobe Acrobat. All I know is that it works well if I want the email to go to the same people every time, which is no longer the case. I am not trying to debug this code. I need to modify it or replace it, so the email addresses change based on the value selected in the drop-down.

Comment: Sir, I have refused nothing. I followed the link associated with your comment to the javascript tag and could not discern what it is. I feel like I've asked someone how to change a tire and they want me to tell them what kind of fuel injection is on the car.

Comment: More like we still don't know if the vehicle is a car, an airplane, or a torpedo boat.

Comment: Will it help if I delete the code from the question?

Comment: No, I don't think that would be an improvement. Probably just leave it for now and see if you get downvotes, close votes, or answers.

Comment: tripleee, I see now where you modified the "PDF" and "Javascript" tags. For future reference, when you said "javascript tag" I thought you were referring to something about javascript, not the post itself. It also created a link, which I followed, to information that was way more complicated than what you were asking, creating further confusion about what was, as you pointed out, a simple request. Thank you for updating those.